# Multiple cronjob emails

Tags: bash, unix, cron

I have 3 jobs in my crontab. I want to recieve emails if only 1 of them fails and not for other two. Is there any way to restric emails to one type of cronjob?

Answer (score 9):

Redirect the output of the two you don't care about to `/dev/null` if you don't ever want to see the output or to some file if you do.

Answer (score 4):

Your cron likely supports this:

```
# This job produces mail.
* * * * * echo Hello

# These jobs do not.
MAILTO=
* * * * * echo Foo
* * * * * echo Bar
```

Comment: Isn't MAILTO= common to all the task in a same crontab file? If the first task produces the email where is the email id specified for that job? I thought MAILTO= is common to all the tasks in crontab file? Or can we have multiple MAILTO='s in a crontab file?

Comment: Depends on your crontab.  Does yours support it?  Mine does.

Comment: MAILTO= applies to all subsequent crontabs.  We use multiples because some people care about some jobs and others care about, well, others.  So we set the MAILTO pretty much before each task and only that person gets the mail. What I'm not sure is that "MAILTO=" (with nothing) actually does anything.  At the very least, I expect the system user would receive the email (ie. locally).  If you really don't want output, piping to /dev/null (if you really don't care) or a file (if you MIGHT care) is better.

Comment: @dotdotdotPaul, from the manpage of the cron package in Ubuntu:

"If MAILTO is defined but empty (MAILTO=""), no mail will be sent."